# How to label functions like getElementById, getElementsByTagName or querySelector?

Tags: javascript, terminology

Sometimes I want to group and label functions like `getElementById`, `getElementsByTagName` and `querySelector`. I used a term "selector functions" to call them but I'm not sure if it's correct one.

Is it ok to use "selector functions" or is there any other term for them?

Comment: I don't think it matters in the slightest, to be honest. Voting to close as ['off-topic,'](http://stackoverflow.com/faq/#questions) though perhaps the discussion might be valid at [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would call them *element selector methods* or *element retrieval methods*.  You need to be careful using the term "selector" though as that is a very common term used in conjunction with jQuery.  You won't want to mislead anyone into thinking that you are talking about [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Also, I used the term method instead of function because that is how they are [defined at w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-102161490).

At the end of the day, it isn't likely going to matter, as long as you clearly communicate your message and/or intent.